# Split a range into n equally sized parts in python

Tags: python, numpy, range

For example, if I have the range of values of 0 to 1, and I want to split it into 3 partitions, I can get the values of 0, 0.5, and 1. If I want 4 partitions, I can use 0, 0.33..., 0.66..., 1, and so on. How can I write a function to do this in Python? I tried writing:

```
import numpy as py

parts = split_into_parts(1, 10)

def split_into_parts(number, n_parts):
    return np.linspace(0, number, n_parts+1)[1:]
```

but this doesn't include the beginning value of 0.

Comment: If you are using numpy, edit your question and add the tag.

Comment: Because you are slicing at the end to take away first value. Try `np.linspace(0, number, n_parts+1)`.

Comment: just remove `[1:]` in your last line

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it returns the list with the zero:

```
import numpy as py

parts = split_into_parts(1, 10)

def split_into_parts(number, n_parts):
    return np.linspace(0, number, n_parts+1)
```